# How to change css elements in HAML dependent on what page is calling for the content?

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, haml

I am an infant when it comes to Ruby and Rails, and still need to learn everything, but I do have one small item I need help with today.

I am working on a header of a website that uses HAML, and I need to change the class name of a `<div>` based on the page that is using it.

**Here is the issue:**

If it is welcome.html.haml, I need a div in header.html.haml to be:

```
.navbar.navbar-inverse.navbar-fixed-top{:role => "navigation"}
```

For all other pages, I need that same div in header.html.haml to be:

```
.navbar.navbar-inverse.navbar-static-top{:role => "navigation"}
```

**I was hoping to use something like:**

```
    - if <PAGE IS> == 'welcome.html.haml'

    .navbar.navbar-inverse.navbar-fixed-top{:role => "navigation"}

    - else

    .navbar.navbar-inverse.navbar-static-top{:role => "navigation"}
```

**I'm just not sure what condition I can give it. I need help with the `<PAGE IS>` part.**

Or, if there is a simpler solution I am all ears.

**EDIT:**

Here is what I tried, but getting errors all over the place:

```
- if controller.action_name == 'welcome'
.navbar.navbar-inverse.navbar-fixed-top{:role => "navigation"}
  .container
- else
.navbar.navbar-inverse.navbar-static-top{:role => "navigation"}
  .container
```

**ANOTHER EDIT:**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the current controller and action using params:

```
if params[:controller] == 'home' && params[:action] == 'welcome'
   ...
end
```

EDIT:

Another solution is to pass a param to your header. In your `welcome.html.haml`

```
= render 'header', navbar: :static
```

And in '_header.html.haml':

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-<%= local_assigns[:navbar] || 'fixed' %>-top" role="navigation">
```

ANOTHER UPDATE:

Of course unless you render header in layout, then it makes absolutely no sense.

Another way of doing this might be `content_for` method.

```
#'welcome.html.haml'
content_for(:navbar_class) { 'fixed' }

#'_header.html.haml'
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-<%= content_for?(:navbar_class) ? yield :navbar_class : 'static' %>-top" role="navigation">
```

Comment: Thanks, I just edited the questions to clarify that the page is always  welcome.html.haml. Not sure if that changes your answer

Comment: Where would I place the ``= render 'header', navbar: :static`` in welcome.html.haml?

Comment: Oh, are you rendering it in header? Then forget. :)

Comment: Oh ok. I imagine there is a simple solution for this? Or am I being too simplistic?

Answer (score 0):

haml code. This should do it:

```
%div.navbar.navbar-inverse{(class: (params[:controller] == 'welcome' ? "navbar-fixed-top" : "navbar-static-top")}
```

Comment: Here's what I have currently, without the logic: ``.navbar.navbar-inverse.navbar-fixed-top{:role => "navigation"}`` Would I need to add to your answer to make it work?

Comment: I'm getting this error when I use your code: ``Illegal nesting: nesting within a tag that already has content is illegal.``

Comment: it works i have done it couple of times. check if your doing it correctly. as far as the role => navigation part i gotta check that. not sure about it.

Comment: Ok, tried a couple more times and still getting that nesting error.

Comment: You're missing one of these: ) Where should I put it?

Comment: I think it's supposed to be like this? ``.navbar.navbar-inverse{class: (params[:controller] == 'welcome' ? "navbar-fixed-top" : "navbar-static-top")}``